# Same query returns different values depending on the presence of UNION statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query

```
declare @datCed DATE = '2022-01-31'
;with t as (        
    SELECT 'CED' AS src, Costo      
    FROM DM_VRECostPerCid_CED   
    WHERE DatCed = @datCed
UNION       
    SELECT 'ADJ' AS src, Importo
    FROM dbo.DM_PY_Adjusted     
    WHERE DatCed = @datCed
)       
select src, sum(costo)  
from t
group by src        

;with t as (        
    SELECT 'CED' AS src, CodAzi, CID, DatCed, CdC, CoGe, Costo      
    FROM DM_VRECostPerCid_CED   
    WHERE DatCed = @datCed
--UNION     
--  SELECT 'ADJ' AS src, CodSoc, CID, DatCed, CdC, CoGe, Importo
--  FROM dbo.DM_PY_Adjusted     
--  WHERE DatCed between '2022-01-31' AND '2022-12-31'  
)       
select src, sum(costo)  
from t
group by src
```

return two **very different** values: the first one returns `18,660,541.37`, and the second returns `31,242,156.23`.
Now, the only difference between the queries is that the **`UNION` and the following SQL statements are commented**.

In my ignorance, I was expecting that the final dataset will be compounds from the two subqueries run independently: in fact, the execution plan gives me the same information, each query run independently and then there is an "Concatenation" operation

Can you explain me what is the interaction in a UNION statement between the subqueries that build the final dataset?
As usual, there will be an easy and evident reason, but I cannot figure what it could be :(

Environment: MSSQL 2008R2
The view DM_VRECostPerCid_CED is defined as

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DM_VRECostPerCid_CED]
AS
SELECT        v.CodAzi, v.CID, v.Liv, v.VRE, v.CoGe, v.DatCed, vg.IDGruppo, SUM(v.Importo) AS Costo, v.CdC
FROM            dbo.DM_VociMese AS v INNER JOIN
                         dbo.DM_VociGruppi AS vg ON v.VRE = vg.VRE AND v.DatCed BETWEEN vg.DatIni AND vg.DatFin LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.DM_TabGruppi AS tg ON vg.IDGruppo = tg.IDGruppo
WHERE        (1 = 1) AND (tg.CostRelevant = 'X')
GROUP BY v.CodAzi, v.CID, v.Liv, v.VRE, v.DatCed, vg.IDGruppo, v.CoGe, v.CdC
GO
```

The table `DM_VociMese` contains +22ml rows, the table `DM_VociGruppi` contains 287 rows and the table `DM_TabGruppi`  contains 36 rows.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I haven't really looked at any detail in the Q but `UNION` gives an implied `DISTINCT` - do you need `UNION ALL`?

Comment: UNION is also doing a DISTINCT of your data set.  You probably want a UNION ALL

Comment: Aside... as Larnu is fond of saying, _`;` is a statement terminator, not a statement begininator._ If you get in the habit of ending all of your SQL statements with `;` (as you should) then you don't have to perform weirdities like `;with` to avoid syntax errors.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys
using `UNION ALL` solved my problem.

Comment: This is an important lesson - generally speaking you should using UNION ALL unless you **know** that you need duplicate removal.